# CasperJS : Recursive casper.open failed with ajax response at the second occurrences

Tags: javascript, ajax, recursion, casperjs, slimerjs

I am using casperJS and slimerJS engine to get videos, loaded by ajax responses.

**steps**

1. Get list of urls
2. Recursive calls on casper.open for each url in the list
3. Each *casper.open* call need to wait the previous *casper.open* send an ajax response.

The two first points work good. I have problem with the third one. 
It's important to understand that i don't need to wait that the page finish to load before to load the next *casper.open*. I just need to wait one ajax response from each url. When i catch this response, i can close this url and open the next one.

To do that, the recursive loop begin with the first occurrence. Then, listen the network with resource.received event and wait for a special contentType. This contentType give me the response where i can find the url to load the video. I store this url in one array and can close thise *casper.open* and begin the next one.

Here is my code :

```
// Some JS code...

function receiver(resource) {
    if (resource.contentType == 'myContentType') {
        sources.push(resource.url);// When catch good conteType, push in sources array
    }
}
casper.on("resource.received", receiver); // Listen responses

// Some JS code...

// Login below
casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluate(function(username, password) {
        document.querySelector('#username').value = username;
        document.querySelector('#password').value = password;
        document.querySelector('#LoginSend').click();
    }, username, password);
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.wait(1000, function() {
        this.waitFor(function() {
            urls = this.evaluate(function() {
                //Get and return all urls
            });
            return true;
        });
    });
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.wait(1000, function() {
        click_link();
    });
});

function click_link() {
    casper.then(function() {
        this.wait(1000, function() {
            this.open(address + urls[i]);// Open new url, i tried with theOpen, don't work too.
            this.waitFor(function() {
                return !!sources[i]; // Wait for the contentType is catch
            }, function() {
                sources.pop(); // Because resource.received has two staged
                this.wait(2000, function() {
                    // Until we don't go to all url, recursive call
                    if (sources.length < urls.length) {
                        i++;
                        click_link();
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    });
}

// Some JS code...
```

The problem is that the first *casper.open* open the page, wait to catch the good contentType and store the good url in my array sources. Then, the next *casper.open* is call and the program stay in the *waitFor* forever. It's because the contentType is never catch... But it's the same kind of page that the previous one. If i begin by this second page first, it works. It's only the next occurrence of the recursive loop which doesn't work, the first occurrence doesn't matter.
Also, if i open these pages in a browser (chrome or firefox), it's working great, he catch the contentType. So, the problem come from my program.
I have an error sometimes during the resource.received listener : "Error type $.cookie". But even if i had jquery.cookie.js, it's not working.

I tried to close the page or to store the cookie and to clear the page between each *casper.open*, but it still not working.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which Slimer.js version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Slimerjs 0.9.6, I already put that listeners before and no errors, but i will try again tonight and let you know if i don't find the problem with that. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I didn't have time to check it before, sorry for that.   
I had already all these event listeners in my program. They gives me no error. Just as i said in my first post, one error with one file received : "$.cookie is not a function"... But even if i had jquery.cookie.js it sill not working.

Comment: In fact i just find it out. I was including "jquery" and "jquery.cookie.js" in the clientScripts options. It was the problem... :( Thank you anyway.